# Getting Initials from a string in R

Tags: r

What is the best way to extract the initials from a string (except for the last word)? For example convert "GEORGE SMITH BROGAN" to "GS BROGAN"

```
NAMES <- data.frame(ID = c("GEORGE SMITH BROGAN","ADAM STEVE WILLIS","UNITED INTERNATIONAL SHIPPING STATION")
```

The desired output for the above names would be GS BROGAN, AS WILLIS, UIS STATION.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try with `gsub`

```
gsub("\\s+(?=[A-Z]\\b)", "", 
   gsub("\\b([A-Z])\\w+\\s|\\s(\\w+)$", "\\1 \\2", NAMES$ID), perl = TRUE)
#[1] "GS BROGAN"   "AS WILLIS"   "UIS STATION"
```

---

Or use `strsplit` with `paste`

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(NAMES$ID), "\\s+"),
  function(x) paste(paste(substr(x[-length(x)], 1, 1), collapse=""), 
      x[length(x)]))
#[1] "GS BROGAN"   "AS WILLIS"   "UIS STATION"
```

Comment: @akrun- Thank you for the answer. I just tried this and noticed there are spaces between the initials. Can we get rid of the spaces  to make "GEORGE SMITH BROGAN" --> "GS BROGAN"

Comment: @Curious  Updated the solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different method using `gsub`:

```
gsub('\\s(?![A-Z]+$)', '', 
     gsub('(?<!\\s|^)[A-Z]+\\s', ' ', NAMES$ID, 
          perl = TRUE), perl = TRUE)
# [1] "GS BROGAN"   "AS WILLIS"   "UIS STATION"
```